# How can I store the object `id` in a migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and MySQL 5.1. I'd like to force to store the object `id` in a migration file. For example I have this:

```
User.create!(
  :name => 'Test name'
)
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
User.create!(
  :id   => '12345', # Force to store the object data with id '12345'
  :name => 'Test name'
)
```

*Note*: the above code will not force the `id` value in the database.

**Is it possible? If so, how?**

Comment: I don't know if something like this is possible, but I don't think it's a good idea to force object IDs. Depending on the setup of your application this might cause ID conflicts, which might break the migration.

Comment: @Koraktor - I use that to set some default data at the application start up time. It is just to initialize the database and to be sure that thing goes as expected.

Comment: use rake task or db:seed for default data?

Comment: @Mikhail Nikalyukin - Why do you ask that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mass assign the restricted fields like `id`. But you can individually set them:

```
user = User.new(:name => 'Test name')
user.id = 12345
user.save!
```

**OR**

```
User.create!(:name => 'Test name') do |user|
  user.id = 12345
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed mass-assign protected fields.  Here's how to do it.  In your model define the following:

```
def attributes_protected_by_default
  default = [ self.class.inheritance_column ]
end
```

What you are doing here is overriding the base method:

```
# The primary key and inheritance column can never be set by mass-assignment for security reasons.
def self.attributes_protected_by_default
  default = [ primary_key, inheritance_column ]
  default << 'id' unless primary_key.eql? 'id'
  default
end
```

...to include only the `inheritance_column` excluding the `id`, or `primary_key` column.  At this point you can now mass-assign the ID for that model.